# Image.getGraphics() causing crash

Tags: java, opengl, slick2d

Whenever I use the method `getGraphics()` from `org.newdawn.slick.Image` in fullscreen mode, it causes a crash. It works perfectly fine in windowed mode, and I've tried doing stuff like `Graphics g = new Image(100,100).getGraphics()`, this also causes the crash.

I am using Slick2D

This is the output I get:

```
Tue May 07 14:58:08 CEST 2013 INFO:Slick Build #264
Tue May 07 14:58:09 CEST 2013 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.9.0
Tue May 07 14:58:09 CEST 2013 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1366 x 768 x 32 @59Hz
Tue May 07 14:58:09 CEST 2013 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 640 x 480 x 32 @59Hz
Tue May 07 14:58:10 CEST 2013 INFO:Starting display 640x480
Tue May 07 14:58:10 CEST 2013 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
Tue May 07 14:58:10 CEST 2013 INFO:Controllers not available
Tue May 07 14:58:10 CEST 2013 INFO:Offscreen Buffers FBO=true PBUFFER=true PBUFFERRT=false
Tue May 07 14:58:10 CEST 2013 DEBUG:Creating FBO 320x240
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x50576337, pid=2120, tid=2300
#
# JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x406337]  ShGetUniformLocation+0x2581e7
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Dadibom\workspace\Game\hs_err_pid2120.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I've tried different images, different resolutions, different framerates, etc. but nothing works when in fullscreen.

I've tried updating my drivers but with no luck!

Comment: It would be REALLY helpful if you provided the code that causes the crash

Comment: It's the method getGraphics()!

Comment: But it also depends on the context. Are you setting some OpenGL parameters?

Comment: I am using Slick2D and using the "standard" initialization code
`public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
  AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new Game(), screenWidth, screenHeight, false);
  app.setTargetFrameRate(60);
  app.setVSync(true);
  app.setShowFPS(false);
  app.start();
 }`

Comment: The problem seems to be in the shared library ig4icd32.dll. It's some intel library for the opengl. Maybe you could try reinstalling your graphics drivers.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I just did, but I get the exact same output ):

Comment: Did you check the other log?
C:\Users\Dadibom\workspace\Game\hs_err_pid2120.log

Comment: [link]http://pastebin.com/wUMiZ33H @NeplatnyUdaj

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is just your GPU is being overloaded when you try to save the screen as an image.

A bit of digging around online suggests you might be working with a computer that uses an lightweight (and low power consuming) integrated GPU for most tasks and is supposed to switch over to a dedicated GPU for things like gaming. The problem then is that your Slick2D game is not triggering the switch from the integrated GPU over to the dedicated GPU.

You can read a bit more in this thread for another Java game:
http://forum.wurmonline.com/index.php?/topic/71698-2fps-and-crashing/?p=708815

The solution suggested is to tell Nvidia to use the dedicated GPU for your Java application.

On the forum thread above, Brash_Endevors points you to a nice video walkthrough of this:
http://www.frequency.com/video/how-to-whitelist-game-with-nvidias/24814032